# Combining multiple scroll divs

Tags: jquery, ipad, iscroll4

I am facing troubles when putting a scrollable div inside another scrollable div. Here is the html code

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="scroller" >
        <div id="wrapper1" style="height: 200px;">
            <div>
                <ul id="thelist1">
                    <li>Pretty row 1</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 2</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 3</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper2" style="height: 200px;">
            <div>
                <ul id="thelist2">
                    <li>Pretty row 1</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 2</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 3</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper3" style="height: 200px;">
            <div>
                <ul id="thelist3">
                    <li>Pretty row 1</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 2</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 3</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 4</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper4" style="height: 200px;">
            <div>
                <ul id="thelist4">
                    <li>Pretty row 1</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 2</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 3</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 4</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

And I am using iscroll plugin for this :

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
myScroll1 = new iScroll('wrapper1');
myScroll2 = new iScroll('wrapper2');
myScroll3 = new iScroll('wrapper3');
myScroll4 = new iScroll('wrapper4');
}
```

The problem is that the event of scrolling the inside div is conflicting with the one of the outside div. So when I scroll one of the inside div, I find my self scrolling the big wrapper div.

Is there a way to scroll only the div which I am touching ?